# uniform distribution vs normal distribution for discount use case

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random

Problem statement: Reward a customer with lucky draw coupon of X% discount in between 1% to 100%

Assume that slabs are pre-defined ( all are theoretical)

> 1% discount   :  90% customers
>
> 10% discount  :  5%  customers
>
> 20% discount  :  3%  customers
>
> 100% discount :  2%  customers

Solution 1: (Uniform distribution, nextInt() in java)

For every 100 customers, I will pre-populate a random array of size 100 with a good shuffling algorithm

> 90 1s ( 1 = 1% discount)
>
> 5 10s ( 10 = 10% discount)
>
> 3 20s ( 20% discount )
>
> 2 100s ( 100% discount)

Whenever a customer comes, I will draw random.nextInt() and get discount percentage in array

Solution 2: (Normal distribution - nextGaussian in java)

Use nextGaussian() of SecureRandom which allows distribution in bell-curve.

Refer to example 1 & 3 in [Random](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62)

> Which one is preferred? - Uniform distribution Vs Normal distribution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is crystal clear. I have to chose one of two solutions as I quoted. I got right response.

Comment: I'm glad my answer worked for you, but I do agree with the others that the question could've been worded more clearly.  There was an element of guesswork on my part.  Attention to clarity does, in general, increase the likelihood of getting relevant answers.

Comment: Still I think I have provided clear details. I have edited the question for clarity purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you would use a normal distribution, which is a bell-shaped curve—not what you want.  Use a uniformly-distributed random variable.

Solution $1$ is acceptable only if you don't care that there is quite a bit of dependence between customer rewards (since it seems you basically assign $90$ one-percent coupons, $5$ ten-percent coupons, $3$ twenty-percent coupons, and $2$ free coupons in cycles of $100$ customers).  This ensures that every $100$ customers, the counts are precisely as expected, but it removes luck entirely from the equation.